# Linear algebra [Intermediate level]

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering how to solve a linear algebra problem.

At first sight it looks easy. But 'between lines'. it isn't.

The problem:

Giving these matrices that are inversible, square (n x n) and are conmutable: A and I (Identity)
$$A^3 - 2A + I = 0$$
and
$$A^{-n} = \left(A^{-1}\right)^n = (A^n)^{-1}$$

Then, what are the values of $x, y$ and $z$, to obtain:
$$A^4 = xA + yI +zA^{-1}$$

**Thanks to user141421 for solving it**

Please, a last help with this point. Giving the same initials conditions, what are the values of $x, y$ and $z$, to obtain:

$$A^{-5} = xA + yI +zA^{-1}$$

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $A^3-2A+I = 0 (\star)$. Multiplying $(\star)$ by $A^{-1}$, we get
$$A^2 = 2I - A^{-1} (\dagger)$$
Multiplying $(\star)$ by $A$, we get
$$A^4 = 2A^2 - A$$
Plugging in $A^2$ from $(\dagger)$, we get
$$A^4 = 2(2I-A^{-1})- A = -A+4I-2A^{-1}$$

---

**EDIT**

Multiplying by $A^{-1}$, we get $A^{-1} = 2I-A^2$.

Again, multiplying by $A^{-1}$, we now have $A^{-2} = 2A^{-1} - A$.

Again, multiplying by $A^{-1}$, we now have $A^{-3} = 2A^{-2} - I = 4A^{-1}-2A-I$.

Again, multiplying by $A^{-1}$, we now have $A^{-4} = 4A^{-2}-2I-A^{-1} = 7A^{-1}-4A-2I$.

Comment: It looks that you have found the solution. But, please, can you help me by writing it down _step by step_. Please, thanks so much in advance.

Comment: @Alejandro I have written down all the steps.

Comment: Now I see it, thanks so much for helping me out ( :

Comment: Can I ask one last question?

Comment: Yes, please.${}{}{}$

Comment: Please, see the last update of my post ( :

Comment: You are a genius. Thanks so much... Please, a last advice. How or where can I find literature on this topic?