# LITERATURE (( Linear algebra [Intermediate level] ))

Tags: linear-algebra

Good day people,

Please, can somebody suggest me some literature on this specific topic:

[Linear algebra [Intermediate level]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/747427/linear-algebra-intermediate-level)

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* is an excellent text for this.